# fancytree on demand loading

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I have a fancytree loading from json file.I need to load on the parent node.once the user clicks a parent the child node for that parent has to load on demand.Other nodes has to close.can anyone tell me.how to implement this

Comment: Free code is not a service provided by SO.

Comment: I am sorry but I am New to jQuery.just an approach or idea to implement will help

Answer (score 0):

[Check fancytree documentation about lazy loading](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#lazy-loading)

**Lazy Loading**

Fancytree supports loading nodes on demand, i.e. only load data when a node is expanded for the first time.

In order to enable this, we can mark nodes as lazy.

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
    // Initial node data that sets 'lazy' flag on some leaf nodes
    source: [
      {title: "Child 1", key: "1", lazy: true},
      {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, lazy: true}
    ],
    lazyLoad: function(event, data) {
      var node = data.node;
      // Issue an ajax request to load child nodes
      data.result = {
        url: "/getBranchData",
        data: {key: node.key}
      }
    }
  });
```